# Переход Swing MVC в Swing+Spring?

Tags: spring, java, swing

Здравствуйте, для облегчения обучения Spring, а так же в учебных целях - решил попробовать переделать(встроить) в Swing приложение Spring.

Приложение клиент-серверное, использует Hibernate для сохраняемых объектов. Начал копать в том направлении - и оказывается на эту тему очень мало написано (источников)...  Что эта ветка в Spring больше никак не развивается, или дальше уже некуда? Или там нет ничего сложного? Просто еще не начинал вчитываться, только собираю инфу.

Вот что я нашел:

- [Introduction to Spring using Swing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-springswing/index.html)
- [Spring with Desktop Application](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?36191-Spring-with-Desktop-Application&highlight=swing)
- [Spring: How to Create Decoupled Swing Components](http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-enabling-decoupled-swin)
- [Spring Rich Client: A practical introduction](http://www.doclo.be/lieven/SpringRichClient.pdf)

**Может кто подскажет другие ресурсы на эту тему (если есть русские), свои соображения на счет задуманного, альтернативу?**

Учитывая то, что переписывать (View) на другом фреймворке нету времени. То есть Swing обязательно остается.

Спасибо!

Comment: Встроить Swing в Spring? Теперь я точно нечего не понимаю в программировании =)

Comment: А по сути? Я ж не из пальца высосал...

Comment: По сути непонятно, что вы делаете и что вы хотите в результате. У вас на свинге декстопное приложение? Причем тут свинг? Учите его? Сделайте отдельный проект и напишите какой-то сайтик...

Comment: Уважаемый, разве из вопроса непонятно? Вы внимательно прочитали, перед тем как отвечать?

ЦИТИРУЮ:

Да, десктопное, думаю это по умолчанию, - если был бы апплет, написал бы. Решил попробовать переделать (встроить) в Swing приложение Spring.

Насчет сайтика. Учитывая то, что переписывать (View) на другом фреймворке нету времени. То есть Swing обязательно остается.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, переписать на спринге стоит только модель Вашего приложения. `View` и `Controller` останутся практически такими же, как и были.